Convert single cell into multiple rows in EXCEL
I converted a pdf file to EXCEL for entering data. Problem is, in the pdf there is a single box which contains multiple new lines. Excel puts all of the data into a single cell. I want to make multiple cells from a single cell. What is the fastest way to do it, as there are more than 100 cells like these.
Here's the picture of the excel.
1
It's D403 , i want all the new lines in separate cells.

The quickest way is to edit the cell content and copy all of it (F2 - Home - Ctrl-Shift-End - Ctrl-C), exit edit mode, and then paste across the cells as desired.

Using search terms "excel parse single cell into rows," I found a useful instructional web site
There's a section specific to your configuration, in that you don't have conveniently comma separated data and that section has the header "Split based on line breaks."

Instead of getting multiple lines in the same cell, I want to split the content of this address so that I get each line in a separate row in a column.
This can again quickly be done using the TEXTSPLIT function, where I
need to somehow use a line break as the delimiter.
And how do I do that?
By using a formula that returns a line break, which can then be used
within the TEXTSPLIT function as the delimiter.
Below is the formula that will split the address using line breaks:
Instead of getting multiple lines in the same cell, I want to split the content of this address so that I get each line in a separate row in a column.
This can again quickly be done using the TEXTSPLIT function, where I
need to somehow use a line break as the delimiter.
And how do I do that?
By using a formula that returns a line break, which can then be used
within the TEXTSPLIT function as the delimiter.
Below is the formula that will split the address using line breaks:

=TEXTSPLIT(A2,,CHAR(10))


Image from linked site.

In the above formula, I have used CHAR(10) as the row delimiter, where
CHAR(10) returns the line break character.


As I am using Office 2010, TEXTSPLIT function is not available. The Text to Columns method successfully converted into columns but when i tried to transpose the column into rows, it gave multiple errors. Regarding the 3rd option, the visual basic code only placed the first element, the rest of the 18 elements were missing, was hoping that the code would work perfectly.

@Zzz Please add a tag to your question indicating your version of Excel.

Here is a VBA solution which will work with the specific problem the OP has described in the question. It uses the VBA SPLIT function which is available in Excel 2010. I have tested it using Excel 365 but have not tested it with Excel 2010. I would be grateful if the routine works in Excel 2010 for the OP to tick the answer to show it works.
When I started out I was hoping to implement the functionality of TEXTSPLIT in VBA but this proved over complicated.
The subroutine only works with the line separator ascii 10 / LF / line feed / char(10)
The subroutine takes a single cell as its first parameter and an integer as its second parameter and returns the string corresponding to the integer after the input cell has been split by line feeds.
Using the test data as suggested by the instructional website, a call like so vbaSPLIT(A1,2) would return "Birdseye"
Function vbaSplit(rCell As Range, iWhichString As Long) As String
    If rCell.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Function ' single cell range only
    Dim sVBLF As String: sVBLF = Chr(10)
    Dim arrSplitStrings() As String
    arrSplitStrings = Split(rCell.Value, sVBLF)
    If iWhichString > UBound(arrSplitStrings) Then Exit Function
    vbaSplit = arrSplitStrings(iWhichString)
End Function

